# Performance Point Dashboard Designer Item Setting

Tags: sharepoint-2013, business-intelligence, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

How do i enable the specify pixels of a web part in the dashboard designer of SharePoint 2013? I can specify pixel for a web part that has a report in it but not for one that contains a filter.

[image]

Comment: Let us know what layout your dashboard is using and what control you are trying to configure

Comment: When I created the dashboard I chose the **1 zone layout** and after that I started creating multiple zones to accommodate filters. What I'm trying to configure is a **performance point MDX filter**.

Answer (score 0):

Not all items within PerformancePoint are sizeable. That is why it is grayed out.

Filters are always sized as auto-size width and auto-size height. You can not configure this at from a webpart configuration standpoint. Its size will auto grow depending on the data contained withing the filter. However it does maintain a minimum width of a filter is 275 pixels. This minimum sizine is implemented via CSS.

It is possible to set a minimum width of a filter by editing the ParameterTree.css file located in _layouts/PPSWebParts/ParameterTree.css. It has width: 275px !Important

Here is a good article called [PerformancePoint Dashboard Sizeing Explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2008/01/07/performancepoint-dashboard-sizing-explained.aspx) from MSDN blogs which goes into detail on this topic.

I am not sure what version you are using. This article is based around 2007 but the concepts still apply. However details such as the minimum size have changed. In 2007 it was 375 and in 2010 it is 275 etc.